# Webpshere Liberty support for Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Does Webpshere Liberty support for Java 9? as of latest beta it is mentioned fully compatible with Java 8 but there is not mentioning about upgrade.  Whether Java 9 Module path can be supported with Websphere liberty?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websphere Liberty mostly works with Java 9 in "toleration mode", meaning that Liberty and apps can run on Java 9, but you can't take advantage of Java 9 modularity yet.

You can find more detailed progress of OpenLiberty (an open-source subset of Websphere Liberty) support for Java 9 here:
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/540

From a Java EE application perspective, it is not yet defined how Java EE apps are supposed to work with JPMS.  That will likely not be decided until Java EE 9.

Comment: Note that the JDK has no notion of "toleration mode". I assume the answer meant to say that it works on the class path without any knowledge of modules.

Comment: That's correct Alan, "toleration mode" is something I made up, which I consider to be a first step of running on Java 9 where no modules are used and we rely on illegal access being enabled.